# How do I determine which Terraform Provider version to use?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

HashiCorp has made clear the [best practice for declaring provider constraints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/requirements.html) within modules. However, the docs don't explain how developers should determine the version number to choose. Documentation on Terraform resources under a provider such as AWS do not indicate provider version that supports that resource nor the provider version number for which attributes listed are supported.

How can I determine which version of Terraform Provider I should use to fulfil my needs? I'm currently using Terraform 0.14.8.

Comment: If you are using the latest version, then why would you want to use old versions which eventually will become deprecated? You have some legacy code to maintain?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the issue. My team at work has set a constraint on an older version of the AWS provider and I'm trying to add a module that has secrets manager related resources. While these resources have existed for a long time so this shouldn't be an issue, there's no way for me to ensure that all resources will be compatible going forward. For example, I know for a fact that the cognito user pool client was recently updated with new code blocks and attribute update.

Comment: I see. I'm not aware of automated way to look at past provider version. I do it the hard-way sadly. When needed I change docs version to older ones at basically random, until I find version which has the attributes I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the latest version available when you need to update from an older version, especially if you're seeking a service that did not exist in your previous provider version. Firstly, you will be getting bugfixes for any of the pre-existing services (and potentially more functionality, if you want to refactor). Secondly, you'll be starting with a recent version of the provider, which should be valid for a considerable time.

Why spend time hunting for the minimum viable version, when you could actually be getting a 1.0 release for the feature that you're adding -- along with all of the potential bugs in a first release?